# Calling windows executable in Azure App Service from code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have app which records from different inputs using h264 encoder in mp4 container. When a video is corrupted we are using `recover_mp4.exe` tool, but there is no Linux support and our Web apps / API's are running under docker containers in Azure App Service, which are Linux.

What options we have to exctract this logic in order to be able to use the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When needing a different platform for specific event-based task I like to use Azure Functions which you can trigger e.g. with a Storage Queue or Service Bus to repair your file. You can run tools like ffmpeg inside Azure functions as [shown here for example](https://gist.github.com/jakkaj/a41aa7ff3ca21426abd66905cf65da11).

Container instances could be another option if you need more control but it's probably the more expensive option.